# Scss naming nested classes or not

Tags: sass

So in `scss` you can reference nested items without giving them class names. Have a look at these examples.

**Not naming them:**

```
.navar {
    ...

    & button {
        background-color: pink;
        ...
    }
}

<div class="navbar">
    <button>One</button>
    <button>Two</button>
    <button>Three</button>
</div>
```

**Naming them:**

```
.navar {
    ...

    & .navbar-button {
        background-color: pink;
        ...
    }
}

<div class="navbar">
    <button class="navbar-button">One</button>
    <button class="navbar-button">Two</button>
    <button class="navbar-button">Three</button>
</div>
```

**Not naming them:**

- PRO: The HTML looks very clean
- CON: It is not obvious a class is affecting the element
- CON: Colleges need to understand the exact nesting design (or copy and paste stuff perfectly)

**Naming them:**

- PRO: It is obvious a class is affecting the element
- CON: The HTML gets cluttered **(especially with Angular in the HTML also)**
- CON: You need to think of a unique self-explaining class name every time

Remember, if you don't know a style is affecting something, then you could run in to a `"what on earth is causing this font to become bold?"` scenario. Imagine a much more nested build than mine (which is not uncommon):

```
.navar {
    & button {
        & div div {
            & a {
                & label {
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But again, an extremely nested scenario like this will make for very clean HTML. Giving each one a class will require you to think of unique class names and make the HTML more visually complex.

**To name nested classes or not to name nested classes, that is the question :)**

For now, I prefer NOT naming them. The HTML just turns out so much prettier. But my problem is, colleges need to understand the exact nesting design to use the styles.

Answer (score 0):

One big con on using styles on tags directly is, that you cannot simply change the html element.

Let's say you have some `<button>` but some day you think it would be better to change this into a `<a>` tag. It would be better to set the styles on the class `.button`. Then you don't have to care about the element. It should just look like a button.

Also when you have deep nested elements that should have styles: Consider using some css naming best practices. I would suggest you using BEM. http://getbem.com/introduction/

It helps you keep your css clean and works well with scss.

Comment: To argue against this, I think it is good to not allow someone to use a `<button>` class on a `<label>`. The class was never meant for a `<label>` and will probably create funky problems if used there. If I want a generic class like `form-control` then I won't specify the `element`. But in most classes I will specify the element to control where people use the class.....regardless, something like my `navbar` example is a style that will never really be used somewhere else (it has very unique hover etc. styles)

Comment: There might be cases, when you don't need extra css classes for your styling. But in most of the cases html tags are agnostic and won't give you any information about their purpuse. E.g. your `& div div` doesn't make any sense to me. Why nesting twice? If there is a css class to one or both divs, it could give me hints why that structure was built and how it should look like.
Some further reading: https://frontstuff.io/you-need-to-stop-targeting-tags-in-css

Comment: Also: When my `<label>` element should look like a button, so that a user clicks it to get focus to the corresponding `<input>` element, then why not giving it a class `.button`? It would totally make sense there.